# xslt - refer to a document in xsl:element

Tags: xslt

i want to refer to an external xml in xls in an element

```
<xsl:element name="{document('mapping.xml', /)/mappings/column/[@id=name()]}" >
```

Is this possible?

**Update**

mapping.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings>
      <columns>
        <column id="path">path</column>
      </columns>
</mappings>
```

Stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:dms="http://www.news.at/dms">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="Mapping" select="document('mapping.xml', /)" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="document">
            <xsl:for-each select="document/*">

            <xsl:element name=
  "{$Mapping/mappings/columns/column[@id = name(current())]}" />


                <xsl:element name="item" >

                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:if test="not($Mapping/mappings/columns/column[@id= name(current())])">
                    <xsl:message>Markup Error: no id attribute in <xsl:value-of select="name(current())" /></xsl:message>
               </xsl:if>        
                        <xsl:value-of select="$Mapping/mappings/columns/column[@id= name(current())]" /></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>     
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<document>
   <path>sdfsdfsdf</path>
</document>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Now it's no reproducible. My output: `<document><path /><item id="path">sdfsdfsdf</item></document>`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely. Like this, though:

```
<xsl:element name="{normalize-space(
  document('mapping.xml', /)/mappings/column[@id=name(current())]
)}" >
```

In plain English: This will select any `<column>` within `/mappings` whose `@id` is equal to the name of the current element in XSLT. The text value of this column will be trimmed via `normalize-space()` and becomes the new `<xsl:element>` name.

*(Note that `comumn[@id=name()]` means "any column whose `@id` is equal to its name", and therefore only matches `<column id="column">`. The `current()` function is necessary to do what you want.)*

It would help, though, to save the document into a global variable first:

```
<!-- at the <xsl:stylesheet> level... -->
<xsl:variable name="mappings" 
  select="document('mapping.xml', /)/mappings/column" 
/>

<!-- later, anywhere... -->
<xsl:element name="{ normalize-space($mappings[@id=name(current())]) }" >
```

Comment: That's exactly what i want. XML Spy always says: "Expecting QName"

Comment: @Hans: Have you tried with a different XSLT processor? The above should actually work - **if** there actually *is* a mapping for the current name. It breaks if there is no mapping, i.e. the inner expression returns empty.

Comment: I don't get the error when i do this: <xsl:value-of select=" $mappings[@id=name(current())] "/>. I can't do it in element

Comment: @Hans: Again: Have you tried in a different XSLT processor than XML Spy?

Comment: I must do it with XML Spy. No choice for an other processor.

Comment: @Hans: I doubt that this is XmlSPY problem. Please provide a complete (but the minimal possible) code example so that people could try to repro your problem. It seems likely that the expression you are providing as AVT in the `name` attribute, has a string value that isn't a legal QName -- such as 123 or ++X.

Comment: @Hans: I agree with Dimitre. Post an XML sample (input.xml, mapping.xml and your XSLT), all files as small as possible. This is impossible to solve without seeing actual code.

Answer (score 1):

> i want to refer to an external xml in
>   xls in an element
>
> ```
> <xsl:element name=
>  "{document('mapping.xml', /)/mappings/column/[@id=name()]}" >
> ```

**Yes, the `name` attribute of the `<xsl:element>` instruction allowas AVTs (Attribute-Value-Template s**)

**The provided code has a number of problems**:

1. **There is an obvious syntax error** in the code you provided:

   `document('mapping.xml', /)/mappings/column/[@id=name()]`

is not a syntactically legal XPath expression. The last location step lacks a node-test and only has a predicate.

.2. **There is nothing in the above expression that relates to the current node in the original XML document**. I guess, the predicate

`[@id=name()]`

should actually be something like:

`[@id=name(current())]`

**So, my guess is that you may want something like**:

```
 <xsl:element name=
  "{document('mapping.xml', /)/mappings/column[@id=name(current())]}" >
```

**There could be an additional, third problem:** (confirmed in a comment by the OP to be the real problem):

The expression specified as AVT in the `name` attribute above may have a string value that is not a syntactically legal QName. Examples of sych illegal values: `123` or `A   B`

**In this case there are different possible solutions**:

- Use the string value of another node (change the XPath expression).
- Transform the offending characters to an allowed character:

...

```
concat(
       translate(substring(yourExpression,1,1), 
                 $illegalFirstCharacters, 
                 '________________'),
       translate(substring(yourExpression,2),
                 $illegalCharacters,
                 '________________')
       )
```

where `$illegalFirstCharacters` is a variable defined to contain all possible characters that may occur as a first character and that are not allowed as a first character of a QName

and `$illegalCharacters`  is a variable defined to contain all possible characters that may occur as after the first character and that are not allowed as in a QName after its first character.

Essentially, `$illegalFirstCharacters` is the concatenation of `$illegalCharacters` and the string `"0123456789"`.

The last argument of `translate()` above must be long enough to accomodate one `_` for each possible illegal character.

This transformation into a valid QName can be expressed much more easily in XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0) using regular expressions.

This solution, of course, should be exercised with caution, because, depending on the actual data, it is possible for two different values that contain illegal QNAme characters, to be converted to the same QName.

Comment: Thanks! The third problem occured. What can I do?

Comment: @Hans: Well, make sure the `<column>` only contains things that are valid XML names, of course.

Comment: @Hans: If it isn't possible to assure that the value is a syntactically-legal QNAme, then you have different possibilities for a workaround. I am updating my answer to describe them.

Comment: @Hans: I just edited my answer describing different possible workarounds to the problem.